# DBT and MWAA integration

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt, mwaa

I am trying to integrate DBT with AWS MWAA and i am getting below error:

```
2021-09-06 07:04:31,290] {{dbt_hook.py:117}} INFO - /usr/local/airflow/.local/bin/dbt run --profiles-dir /usr/local/airflow/dags/dbt/
[2021-09-06 07:04:31,326] {{dbt_hook.py:126}} INFO - Output:
[2021-09-06 07:04:33,280] {{dbt_hook.py:130}} INFO - Running with dbt=0.20.1
[2021-09-06 07:04:35,416] {{dbt_hook.py:130}} INFO - Encountered an error:
[2021-09-06 07:04:35,450] {{dbt_hook.py:130}} INFO - [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'target/partial_parse.msgpack'
[2021-09-06 07:04:35,636] {{dbt_hook.py:134}} INFO - Command exited with return code 2
```

My Dag is :

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow_dbt.operators.dbt_operator import (
    DbtSeedOperator,
    DbtSnapshotOperator,
    DbtRunOperator,
    DbtTestOperator
)
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago


default_args = {
    'start_date': days_ago(0)
}

with DAG(dag_id='dbt_snow', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='@daily') as dag:
    dbt_run = DbtRunOperator(
        task_id='dbt_run',
        dbt_bin='/usr/local/airflow/.local/bin/dbt',
        profiles_dir='/usr/local/airflow/dags/dbt/',
        dir='/usr/local/airflow/dags/dbt/learn/'
    )
```

I am using the plugin provided :

```
https://github.com/gocardless/airflow-dbt

https://pypi.org/project/airflow-dbt/

https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/running-a-dbt-project/running-dbt-in-production#using-airflow
```

I tried removing partial parsing by adding config to false and even then i am getting this error.

Any pointer on how to resolve it.

Comment: What did you run that gives this error?

Comment: it does a dbt run as shown in message first line . I am writing to snowflake to add more context.

Comment: Can you add the approrpriate snowflake-related tag?

Comment: I have added the tag but i am assuming the partial parse error is not only for snowflake.

Comment: Can you give us enough information and code to reproduce the error?

Comment: Updated with Dag and plugin which has been mentioned in DBT document

Answer (score 0):

changing the target and logs location to the following made it work:

```
/usr/local/airflow/dags/dbt/
```

So we need to ship them back, as per the need.

Comment: I'm running my dbt model from airflow-mwaa environment and it failed with the Database Error , 001003 (42000): SQL compilation error: , syntax error line 1 at position 48 unexpected '<EOF>'. , syntax error line 1 at position 47 unexpected '.'. in airflow dag logs, and surprisingly the same dbt project ran fine without any issues in my local dbt-core environment. Did any boday faced the same with dbt-core. airflow-mwaa environment.